# how to run Django application in apache2

Tags: python, django, apache2

Hi All i am not able to run a django application in apache2 webserver. I have went through all the document but it still did not work for me.This is my Apache2's httpd.conf file

```
<Location "/mysite/">
  SetHandler python-program
  PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
  SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
  PythonOption django.root /mysite
  PythonPath "['/home/djangotest/mysite'] + sys.path"
  PythonDebug On
</Location>
```

My django project location is at /home/djangotest/mysite in which i am running the polls application. Is there something i have to mention in settings.py or urls.py for this to work in apache2 it works fine in the dev server. or is there configuration i have to do in apache2 to work

Comment: please do not use mod_pythom, use mod_wsgi instead :'(

Comment: i have switched to mod_wsgi and trying it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add '/home/djangotest' to PythonPath:

```
<Location "/mysite/">

  SetHandler python-program
  PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
  SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
  PythonOption django.root /mysite
  PythonPath "['/home/djangotest', '/home/djangotest/mysite'] + sys.path"

  PythonDebug On
</Location>
```

You need to add that if you import your project's files with the syntax ..
The other guys here are right, though; switch to mod-wsgi if you can. Django's mod_python support will be deprecated very soon. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modpython/

edit: mod_python support is deprecated in Django 1.3, and will be removed entirely on Django 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download and install  http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz
2. Add to the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ directory

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName --insert--

  ErrorLog /home/djangotest/mysite/error_log
  CustomLog /home/djangotest/mysite/access_log combined

  UseCanonicalName Off

  WSGIScriptAlias /g2 /home/djangotest/mysite/mysite.wsgi
  WSGIDaemonProcess iproj processes=7 threads=1 display-name=%{GROUP}

</VirtualHost>
```

1. Add to LoadModules secion in  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

   LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
2. Add to AddHandler section in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

   AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
3. Make sure your the httpd user can access /home/djangotest/ as well as execute your python scripts
4. Create a mysite.wsgi file:

---

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/djangotest/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Or as @Efazati said, read the manual ;)

---

Hopefuly this solves your final issue:

> no module named mysite.urls but there is a file urls.py

Check your settings file for

> ROOT_URLCONF = "mysite.urls"

This is the name of your urls file, I am guessing you dont have a module called mysite.urls.py ?  It sounds like your property should read:

> ROOT_URLCONF = "urls"

Comment: So you're saying download mod_wsgi, then use mod_python??

Comment: I tried wt u said but i get an import error no module named mysite.urls but there is a file urls.py

Comment: I dont have any reference to mysite.urls ? You are going to have to explain....?  It sounds like an issue with your settings file, or your python path.

Comment: This is wt i have done in my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file i have put LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/djangotest/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
and i created an wsgi file in apache folder with the code u have sent is there something i have to add in mysite/setting.py

Comment: Thanks for the ROOT_URLCONF suggestion! Just curious why the file gets named urls.py and the default path in settings is mysite.urls.py ?

Answer (score 0):

read the manual

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/